# How to get editable td value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I a table in which i mark td as a editable i assign a unique id to it as well but in javascript side i unable to get the value(innerText). Here is html:

```
<td style="text-align: left" id="145_no" contenteditable="true" ng-blur="editTranslation(ft)" class="glowing-border ng-binding"><font><font>some value which user write</font></font></td>
```

This is how i tried to get text in javascript side:

```
var tdElem = document.getElementById ( "145_no" );
 var tdText = tdElem.innerText | tdElem.textContent;
```

result always shows as empty string. Can someone suggest a proper way. I want to implement this for both firefox and chrome.

---------------- complete code---------

html:

```
  <tr class="statistics_table_row cursor"
                        data-ng-repeat="ft in flagsWithTranslation | filter:{language:'no'} | orderBy:'flag'">
                        <td width="20%" style="text-align: left">{{ ft.flag }}</td>
                        <td style="text-align: left" id="{{ft.id}}_{{ft.language}}" contentEditable="true"
                            ng-blur="editTranslation(ft)" class="glowing-border">{{ ft.translation }}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

javascript:

```
 $scope.editTranslation = function (flagTranslation) {
    var editTranslation = "", temp = "";
    var tdElem = document.getElementById ( flagTranslation.id + "_" + flagTranslation.language );
    var tdText = tdElem.innerText || tdElem.textContent;
    $log.info("tdText: " + tdText);

  ......
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

you should use logical "||" OR operator rather than bitwise or "|" operator

```js
function editTranslation(){
var tdElem = document.getElementById("145_no" );
 var tdText = tdElem.innerText || tdElem.textContent; 
  console.log(tdText);
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
<td style="text-align: left" id="145_no" contenteditable="true" onblur="editTranslation()" class="glowing-border ng-binding"><font><font>some value which user write</font></font></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: @user526206 do you see any error in console, it should work. Try to run the code snippet above,

Comment: Yea it is working here. but somehow not in my application and there is no error in console..

Comment: so that's the first lead for your solution, further investigation is required at your end

Comment: i just updated question with actual code. I am not getting it where is a mistake. Can you please have a look in to it.